# Static Variable in IIS ASP.NET application with 2 instances

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have a single code folder, **c:\some-ASPNETMVC-site**

That folder is pointed to by **2 IIS7 Sites**, each site has its **own application pool**.

If I set a static variable, in this case a log4net appender's log file path, at run time to a value different in each site, will the values over write each other, or will it be considered 2 applications and be independent of each other?

Comment: Since each app pool spawns its own IIS worker process, I would assume it would be considered 2 applications and maintain independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [TechNet Article on IIS Application Pools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735247%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

> An Internet Information Services (IIS) application pool is a grouping
>   of URLs that is routed to one or more worker processes. Because
>   application pools define a set of Web applications that share one or
>   more worker processes, they provide a convenient way to administer a
>   set of Web sites and applications and their corresponding worker
>   processes. Process boundaries separate each worker process; therefore,
>   a Web site or application in one application pool will not be affected
>   by application problems in other application pools. Application pools
>   significantly increase both the reliability and manageability of a Web
>   infrastructure.

Given that each application pool is its own set of worker processes, each static variable would be unique in that instance and should not be shared if setting the value at runtime.